# Batch Normalization causes infinitely negative loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, batch-normalization

I added a few convolutional layers with batch normalization to an image segmentation model (also containing batch normalization) that I had already trained. When I begin fine-tuning by freezing the image segmentation model and training only the new layers, the cross-entropy loss rapidly drops and becomes negative infinity/NaN within 1-2 epochs. Without batch normalization layers, the loss does not explode but the network also does not learn well.

I think the behavior has to do with the difference in batch normalization behavior in inference and training mode. I have tried training the combined model without freezing any layers, and tried setting only the batch norm layers to be "trainable=false", but the loss still doesn't converge. I also tried decreasing the learning rate by several orders of magnitude (ADAM optimizer, LR=1e-3 to 1e-6). Do you have any suggestions for why batch normalization would prevent convergence? Is it possible that putting batch normalization after each of the 4 convolutional layers is overkill?

I am using tensorflow 2.0 beta and the tf.keras implementation of the batch norm layer.

Comment: We cannot help you without seeing some code. Cross-entropy should never be negative, so it is likely that your code is buggy. Please provide a _minimal_ reproducible example that displays the issue.

Comment: Maybe the problem is at your dataset. Maybe your train data is not sufficient for your network to learn? How many train and test data you have?

Comment: Thank you for the comments, it turns out I was using single channel binary images as my labels instead of one-hot encoded labels and this was leading to the negative cross entropy loss. The batch normalization is still causing some issues but not exploding negative loss!